# миниПарсер SQL запросов

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно вытащить названия основных таблиц `Select ... From TableName`
Имеются запросы четырёх типов:

```
1. Select ... From TableName

2. Select ... From Only TableName

3. Select ... From TableName1
   Union
   Select ... From TableName2

4. Select ...,
     Exists(SELECT true FROM _tName WHERE ...)
   From TableName
```

Написал регулярку: (с параметрами gims тестил [тут](https://regex101.com/)) (запросы страшние с множественными переносами строк, табуляторами и пробелами, потому вставлял везде `\s\t\r\n`)

```
(?:[\s\t\r\n]*select.+?from[\s\t\r\n]*(?:only|)[\s\t\r\n]*)(\S*)
```

Обламывается на 4ом примере, как учесть в ней подзапросы?
Например, чтобы выбирала только `Select..From` между которыми нет ещё одного `Select`. Если просто делать жадным, то не находятся все таблицы при `Union`

Comment: удалить перед обработкой все exists\\(.+?\\) не вариант?

Comment: Что именно Вы хотите выбрать ? Какой select ? Который в подзапросе ? Ваше регулярное выражение и так это делает: https://regex101.com/r/pK5xW3/1

Comment: @ReinRaus, в четвертом варианте не правильно делает, т.к. что в подзапросе мне не интересно, а основной запрос оно не находит, единственный недочёт

Comment: @norbornen, вариант, но он мне не очень нравится, хотелось бы не городить, а решить всё в одной регулярке

Comment: @Isaev, зато так проще, наглядней и, скорее всего, быстрее (в зависимости от языка).

Comment: @Isaev: Ох. Что-то мне кажется, «мини» не получится. Если есть рекурсия, придётся писать полновесный парсер.

Comment: @norbornen, в пхп нагляднее вроде, в дельфи в данном случае очень не наглядно, а по скорости наверняка в любом языке медленнее

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решается банальной рекурсией в регулярном выражении.
Извините за странное написание. Привычка.

```
(?P<onlyselect>\bselect\s*.*?\bfrom\s*+(?:only)?\s*+\S++){0}\bselect\s*(?:(?P>onlyselect)|.)*?\bfrom\s*+(?:only)?\s*+(\S++) 
# IGNORECASE DOTALL
```

Входящий текст:

```
1. Select ...
 From TableName1

2. Select ... From Only TableName2

3. Select ... From TableName3
   Union
   Select ... From TableName4

4. Select ...,
     Exists(SELECT true FROM TableName5 WHERE ...)
   From TableName6
```

Результат:

```
MATCH 1
2.  [20-30] `TableName1`
MATCH 2
2.  [56-66] `TableName2`
MATCH 3
2.  [87-97] `TableName3`
MATCH 4
2.  [126-136]   `TableName4`
MATCH 5
2.  [212-222]   `TableName6`
```

https://regex101.com/r/pK5xW3/3
**P.S.** Регулярное выражение не учитывает комментарии, CDATA и прочие прелести SQL-запросов. Оно просто решает задачу, поставленную в вопросе.

Comment: То, что надо! Благодарствую) И пойду изучать банальную рекурсию в регулярных выражениях, не слышал об этом, к сожалению

Comment: Дж.Фридл. "Регулярные выражения". Лучшее что есть по теме.