# Ошибка RegularExpressions.pas или моя?

Tags: delphi, регулярные-выражения

Псевдопродолжение [темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419865/)

Есть регулярное выражение: [пример на regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pK5xW3/4)

Там в примере всё отрабатывает нормально, а в коде на Delphi:

```
unit MyUnit;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, RegularExpressions, StrUtils;

type
  THauptForm = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    Function ReplaceCC(Const Match: TMatch): String;
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  HauptForm: THauptForm;
  FMatchCollection: TMatchCollection;
  FReplaceCounter: Integer;
  FAltSql: String;

Implementation

{$R *.dfm}

Function THauptForm.ReplaceCC(Const Match: TMatch): String;
Var
  Pc: pChar;
  P: Integer;
Begin
  Result:=FMatchCollection[FReplaceCounter].Value;
  //поиск с конца
  Pc:=SearchBuf(pChar(Result), Length(Result), Length(Result)-1, Length(Result), 'from ', []);
  If Pc=Nil Then P:=0
  Else Begin
    P:=Pc-pChar(Result)+1;
    While Not(IsCharAlphaNumeric(Result[P-1])) Do
      Dec(P);
  End;
  If P>0 Then Begin
    Insert(', (TSystem.Get_PrintSettings('+FMatchCollection[FReplaceCounter].Groups[2].Value+'.dbrid)).*', Result, P);
    Inc(FReplaceCounter);
  End;
End;

Procedure THauptForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Var
  RegEx: TRegEx;
  MyEval: TMatchEvaluator;
  tStr: TStringList;
Begin
  tStr:=TStringList.Create;
  tStr.Clear;
  tStr.Add('SELECT table1.*, adr1 AS name1, adr2 AS name2, adr3 AS name3,');
  tStr.Add('lang1 AS l1,');
  tStr.Add('lang_hrtgc_id(belhtrp_mce, current_l()) AS _mengenbezih, lang_artmghrrc_id(belhtrp_mce) AS _mengenisond,');
  tStr.Add('lang_hrt_id(belhtrp_mce, current_l()) AS _mengenbezih2, lang_artmghrrc_id(belhtrp_mce) AS _mengenisond2,');
  tStr.Add('dbf3g_hrtgc_id(belp_nr, current_l()) AS _artzzzbez,');
  tStr.Add('TDlrki.IntToStr(belp_id) AS vhrewter_berz,');
  tStr.Add('ks_bks AS belp_ks_bez, er_bez AS belp_konto_bez,');
  tStr.Add('CASE WHEN belp_gtyp = ''LFS'' THEN Exists(SELECT true FROM lifschwerg WHERE l_id = belp_id) ELSE FALSE END AS hasCreeeZbg');
  tStr.Add('FROM betpos LEFT JOIN ksv ON ks_abt=belp_koslle LEFT JOIN erfdloes ON er_to=belp_ko');
  tStr.Add('WHERE belp_id = :betttlegid ORDER BY belp_po');

  FAltSql:=tStr.Text;

  RegEx:=TRegEx.Create('(?P<onlyselect>\bselect\s*.*?\bfrom\s*+(?:only)?\s*+\S++){0}\bselect\s*(?:(?P>onlyselect)|.)*?\bfrom\s*+(?:only)?\s*+(\S++)', [roIgnoreCase, roSingleLine]);
  If RegEx.IsMatch(FAltSql) Then Begin
    FReplaceCounter:=0;
    FMatchCollection:=RegEx.Matches(FAltSql);
    MyEval:=ReplaceCC;
    Memo1.Lines.Text:=RegEx.Replace(FAltSql, MyEval);
  End;

  tStr.Free;
End;

End.
```

Падает при разборе регулярки ошибкой переполнения стека. В чём причина?
Думал эта библиотека не поддерживает рекурсию в выражениях, то если несколько строк при задании входной строки закомментировать, то работает. Но стек действительно полный, так много вызовов не должно происходить по идее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уменьшил количество возвратов в **7 (семь !)** раз. Если и в этот раз будет падать по переполнению стэка, то предлагаю сменить язык на котором Вы пишете, либо используйте сторонние библиотеки PCRE в нем.
https://regex101.com/r/pK5xW3/6

```
\bselect\s*+(?:(?P>onlyselect)|[^sf]++|[sf])*?\bfrom\s*+(?:only)?\s*+(\S++)(?:(?!)(?P<onlyselect>\bselect\s*+(?:[^f]++|f)*?\bfrom\s*+(?:only)?\s*+\S++)){0}
```

Входной текст:

```
SELECT table1.*, adr1 AS name1, adr2 AS name2, adr3 AS name3,
lang1 AS l1,
lang_hrtgc_id(belhtrp_mce, current_l()) AS _mengenbezih, lang_artmghrrc_id(belhtrp_mce) AS _mengenisond,
lang_hrt_id(belhtrp_mce, current_l()) AS _mengenbezih2, lang_artmghrrc_id(belhtrp_mce) AS _mengenisond2,
dbf3g_hrtgc_id(belp_nr, current_l()) AS _artzzzbez,
TDlrki.IntToStr(belp_id) AS vhrewter_berz,
ks_bks AS belp_ks_bez, er_bez AS belp_konto_bez,
CASE WHEN belp_gtyp = ''LFS'' THEN Exists(SELECT true FROM lifschwerg WHERE l_id = belp_id) ELSE FALSE END AS hasCreeeZbg
FROM betpos LEFT JOIN ksv ON ks_abt=belp_koslle LEFT JOIN erfdloes ON er_to=belp_ko
WHERE belp_id = :betttlegid ORDER BY belp_po
```

Результат:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [556-562]   `betpos`
```

Comment: respect! То, что работало, стало работать заметно шустрее. Именно этот пример больше не падает, но подвисает заметно всё равно. Странно почему именно он, что в нём такого особенного? Каким образом удалось добиться уменьшения рекурсии? Почему именно в 7 раз? Где видно количество возвратов?

Comment: @Isaev, на данном конкретном тексте в 7 раз. Смотрите количество STEPS по Вашей ревизии регулярки и по моей. У Вас 2800, по моей 400.

Comment: Уменьшение засчет снижения возвратов при минимальной квантификации **\*?**

Answer (score 0):

Чем сложнее регулярное выражение, чем больше текст и чем больше потенциальное число вхождений его частей, тем дольше будет разбираться текст. Рекурсия - это явно не самая хорошая часть регулярных выражений, вполне возможно, что попыток найти рекурсивное совпадение слишком много и стек переполняется.

Comment: так рекурсия ищет Select/From между Select и From, это 1 вхождение в данном случае, на чём оно циклится? На других текстах, которые больше по размеру и по количеству вхождений всё исправно отрабатывает, а тут какой-то камень. Дебаггером в дебрях библиотеки заблудился, может само выражение можно составить корректнее? может что-то не учтено просто?

Comment: А эта строка точно ему соответствует? Если она не соответствует, то может быть намного больше уилий на её проверку. И вообще, вряд ли регулярные выражения хороший способ для разбора sql-запросов. Думаю, можно было бы реализовать линейный парсер по аналогии с парсером математических выражений.

Comment: единственная различие, что в Delphi присутствуют переносы строк #10#13 после каждой строки, а при тесте online их нет, но `\s*+` должна их всё равно отсекать.

линейный парсер конечно лучше, не спорю... может если этот метод очень не подойдёт или будет требовать расширения функциональности я на него и перейду, но сейчас мне интересно в чём именно загвоздка в данном случае